# Basis of tensor product of two vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products

I'm doing a proof of just two spaces, so $V^* \otimes W^*$ has basis

$$\{\epsilon^{(1)}_{i_1} \otimes \epsilon^{(2)}_{i_2} \mid 1\leq i_1 \leq n_1,1\leq i_2 \leq n_2\}$$

For any $w_1\otimes w_2$ in these dual spaces respectively, we write them wrt. their basis, i.e. there exist constants $a_{1_1},...,a_{n_1},b_{1_2},...,b_{n_2}$ to write out $w_1$ and $w_2$. 
Is the following a correct assertion?

$$\forall v\in V : w_1(v) =  \sum_{i_1=1}^{n_1} a_{i_1}\epsilon_{i_1}(v)$$

$$\forall v\in W : w_2(v) =  \sum_{i_2=1}^{n_2} b_{i_2}\epsilon_{i_2}(v)$$

As long as I haven't messed this up the rest is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, if $V,W$ are vector spaces with basis $\{v_i\}_{i=1}^n$ resp. $\{w_j\}_{j=1}^m$ it holds that $V \otimes W$ has as basis $\{v_i \otimes w_j\}_{i,j}$.

Comment: yes, but say I set out to prove that it's true. I'm simply seeking whether the two statements are true.

Comment: You can indeed write $w_1$ and $w_2$ as you do. I also see that your indices are a little bit screwed: $a_{1_1}$ means $a_1$ etc.

Comment: Alright! Thanks a bunch. As for indices, I have been trying to keep them in line with my textbook. This being a case of two spaces, I could easily simplify.  You're right to point it out my clumsiness :)